# How to find encoding options for specific format/codec in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

when typing `ffmpeg -h long`, it says to type `ffmpeg -h type=name` for a specific codec, but typing this (for webp) results with `Unknown help option 'type'` and the results of `ffmpeg -h`. basically, how do i find the options for a specific format/output type, e.g. find the options for `libvpx-vp9` such as finding out how `-crf` works. specifically, what i am trying to do is extract images from flacs so i may re-encode them into `.opus` files using `opusenc` from the `opus-tools` package with album art. it may sound odd but conversions from flac to opus using ffmpeg always exclude the album covers. i am trying to find a way to shrink these images to about 50kb, because the originals are close to 1mb.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace `type` with the type of the thing that you want information of, e.g. `encoder`, `decoder`, `filter`. Therefore, you must enter `ffmpeg -h encoder=webp` or `ffmpeg -h encoder=libvpx-vp9`.